# Internet Explorer(8/9) ignores new line characters while printing plain text

Tags: internet-explorer

I show jBoss logs via browsers. In Firefox each line of log is ended by a new line (as it should) - IE 8 and 9 shows the entire log as a huge blob and not with new line after each line in the log file. 
When I open a file with .txt extension, IE and Firefox adds < pre > tag around the content and content is displayed fine.
But when the file is .log file, IE simply dumps the content. source looks like :

```
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD> <BODY>content of the log</BODY></HTML>
```

Anyone faced this nuisance ?

Comment: I have no control how .log files are generated by jBoss, so I can not add <br/> tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure that your web server is delivering `.log` files as MIME type `text/plain`, not as `text/html`. This way, even IE will handle this not as a malformed HTML file but as a plain text file.

Comment: Thanks @SvenW, Can you tell me how to check that ? I made sure that the registry "Content Type" for .log file is "text-plain" - what else is required ?

Comment: +1 The problem is the log file contains only LF. Windows and it's brethern (Internet Explorer included) will not recognize this as an End of Line character without the preceeding CR. IE can be tricked into compliance by setting the MIME type as SvenW points out.

Comment: I am directing to jboss/logs directory that shows a list of log files. On clicking server.log, I intend to show the log file in browser window. Where do I set the MIME type ?

Comment: On your web server, whatever one you use to serve the log files (I don't know anything about this Java Web stuff, it might entirely be that JBoss *is* a web server).

Comment: Added the following mime-type to log.war's web.xml     <mime-mapping>
        <extension>log</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>